# Zeppelin %sql cannot access temporary table

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have three Zeppelin (0.6) paragraphs:

para1:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val df = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM tweetsORC")
z.put("wds", df)
```

para2:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame                            
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = z.get("wds").asInstanceOf[DataFrame]
df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value")).groupBy("value").count().sort(desc("count")).show(20, false)
df.registerTempTable("top20")
```

para3:

```
%sql
select * from top20
```

this gives the following error:

```
Table not found: top20
```

I assume this is because the table is part of the hivecontext and sql cannot see it. I have seen some solutions to similar problems that suggest creating a sqlcontext is the problem, but I have not done this. So how can the %sql paragraph access the temp table? Any pointers are greatly appreciated. (I want to use %sql for the nice built-in graphs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interoperability between interpreters is provided only when you use the contexts provided for you by the Zeppelin (as `sqlContext`). Once you create your own context here:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

it is not connected in any way to the context used by `%sql` and `Table not found` is the expected error.

Solution: use `sqlContext` to create and register tables.

Comment: Thanks user. Can you explain a little further? Does this mean I can just change val df = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM tweetsORC") to val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tweetsORC")?